# Unfamiliar notations about $\pi\pi\rightarrow\pi\pi$ scattering amplitudes in Weinberg’s QFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, effective-field-theory, pions, isospin-symmetry

I’m reading section 19.5 of Weinberg’s second volume of QFT, and confused about some notations. In that chapter, he introduce the non linear sigma model as an low energy effective theory of 2-flavor QCD, and its Lagrangian is
$$\mathcal{L}=-\frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu\pi_a\partial^\mu\pi_a-\frac{m_\pi^2}{2}\pi_a\pi_a+\frac{1}{F_\pi^4}(\partial_\mu \pi_a\partial^\mu\pi_a)\pi_b\pi_b+\frac{m_\pi^2}{2F_\pi^2}\pi_a\pi_a\pi_b\pi_b+(\mathrm{higher}\ \mathrm{terms}),$$
where Latin-alphabet indices $a,b=1,2,3$ denote legs of isospin $T=1$.

Next, he analyzes the $\pi\pi\rightarrow\pi\pi$ scattering process as a application of this Lagrangian.
By straight forward calculations, we obtain a following  expression:
$$M^{(\nu=2)}_{abcd}=4F_\pi^{-2}\big[\delta_{ab}\delta_{cd} (s-m_\pi^2)+\delta_{ac}\delta_{bd}(t-m_\pi^2)+\delta_{ad}\delta_{bc}(u-m_\pi^2)\big].\ \ \ \ \ \ \ (19.5.35)$$
I have no question until this expression. However, at this point, he introduces some tensors that are unfamiliar for me, that is
$$M^{(0)}_{ab,cd}=\frac{1}{3}\delta_{ab}\delta_{cd},\ \ \ \ \ \ (19.5.37)$$
$$M^{(2)}_{ab,cd}=\frac{1}{2}(\delta_{ac}\delta_{bd}+\delta_{ad}\delta_{bc}-\frac{2}{3}\delta_{ab}\delta_{cd}).\ \ \ \ \ \ (19.5.38)$$
He says these tensors represent two-pion states with isospin $T=0$ or $T=2$, but I could not understand this point.

$\textbf{Why do these tensors represent two-pion states?}$

I feel these are related to the Clebsch-Gordan coefficient, but I could not check it clearly.

Answer (score 1):

A symmetric bilinear of isotriplet pions reduces to an
isosinglet, and a traceless symmetric tensor isoquintet,
$$\pi^a \pi^b = \frac{1}{3} \delta^{ab} ~~~+ ~~~ \left (\pi^a \pi^b  -\frac{1}{3} \delta^{ab}\right ).
$$
(In angular momentum, you know this in the symmetric composition of two vectors, so one spinless singlet and 5 spin-2 states.) So what propagates is not the 6-state symmetric rank 2-tensor, but a disjoint 5 and a 1.

The author propagates these two rank 2 tensors  by the hyper cubic matrix *M* mapping 2-tensors to 2-tensors. In separate  invariant subspaces, as he states below your formulas, where the trace is normalized by their respective dimensionalities, 1, and 5 for isospin 0 and 2, so, then $2T+1$.

So you may indeed check that tracing the respective
hypercubic *M*s by saturating with $\delta^{ac}\delta^{bd}$ yields 1 for (19.5.37) and 5 for (19.5.38): The isosinglet and the isoquinted never talk to each other.